# I cannot change the size of the icon in my menu bar

Tags: android, menuitem

I have the following bottom navigation bar with the two icons which I would like to increase the sizes of.

[image]

I have added the following line of code in my `dimens.xml` file which should override the default size but it is not working as you can see.

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this!?

Comment: Hi! Did you have a chance to check my answer below? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73505302/2271651

Comment: @sergpetrov so does your answer mean you can NOT increase the size of the icons?

Comment: I mean it's better to follow the official guidelines first then if it's not suitable for you find a workaround.
Can you show your layout xml where you are setting the bottom bar and icons, please?

Answer (score 0):

The `design_navigation_icon_size` is used for NavigationView but it looks like you are using [BottomBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar), so the easiest way is just to follow the official [guidelines](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom#specs) and have the icons with the according size (24dp x 24dp).

[image]